# Eclipse Discovery Options in LUNA

Tags: c++, eclipse

As described in LUNA the Discovery Options have been deprecated, use Preprocessor ....   In Indigo, we create a file using make FLG=on &> , using the file and the Discovery Options we can easily resolve the includes for a project. To date in LUNA we have been unable to accomplish the same resolution.  Are we simply going to have to do manually or are there a capability we haven't Discovery yet?

Comment: Thanks for the information, it get me real close  (worked as described). Unfortunately, still missing the includes in the project, any ideas?

Comment: Since make only calls the compile command when needed, you will need to make clean once before building in eclipse so that the compile command is called for each source file.  After a clean compile, sometimes you will need to right click on the project and select 'rebuild index'  You will know if the indexer has been run on a file (or folder) if there is a little wrench icon attached to the tree item in the project explorer.

Answer (score 3):

The new method for Discovery only works with build output in the eclipse console.  It cannot load build output from a file as the old Discovery could. In project->properties select the C/C++ Build item in the left pane then select the Builder Settings tab.  Uncheck 'Use default build command' and change the build command to 'make FLG=on' (If using CMake this would be 'make VERBOSE=1'). In previous versions you would also have to make sure that you are doing non-parallel builds by deselecting the 'Enable parallel build' check box on the "Behavior" tab.  The reason is that make would jumble together parallel output making it difficult to parse.  I haven't checked if this is still the case in Luna because I switched to ninja-build which does not jumble parallel build output (and results in much faster builds).  If you decide to switch to ninja-build yourself, add the -v flag for verbose output needed by the parser.

Keys to getting the "new" Discovery working

1) Make sure you are generating verbose output.  Eclipse is looking for the -I and -D flags. Verify that you are seeing the -I and -D's by checking the CDT Build Console output.

2) Make sure the build output isn't jumbled by either using non-parallel builds, or by using a build system that doesn't jumble parallel build output such as ninja-build.

3) Make sure that the build parser can detect your compile command.  Go to project->properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor Includes Then click on the Providers tab.  It will show you a list of providers.  Click on the 'CDT GCC Build Output Parser' provider.  Make sure that the regular expression matches your *entire* specific compiler command.  I did this by copy-pasting the build output into a text editor then searched for the pattern using the regular expression.  Here is the pattern I ended up using (gcc)|([gc]++)|(clang)|([.*] .*[gc]++) | ([.*] .*g?cc ).

Comment: Hmm, My approach is to prepare the compiler output before hand and just 'cat' is as a part of build in eclipse. Nothing I can do seemsto work, eclipse ignores the output. My output is few lines one of which is: `g++ -M  -DLinux  -DPOSIX -I/cygdrive/c/dev/boost`      boost does not appear in the 'includes' I' after building. any hints?

Comment: Okay. Finally! It worked. All I had to do is in the Provider -> OutputParser settings select "Container to keep discvoered entries" -> Project ( last option )